# How to manage multiple dependencies in useEffect that influence one another

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

Firstly I had useEffect for each of the dependency (making 7 requests on load) which I didn't like. Now I implemented query params, so if you go from

> /clients?page=2&search=test

to

> /clients/:id

and from there when you go back, you should be again on same page with same search.
But I have several filters.

1. Search
2. Page
3. page size
4. company
5. agent

And I wanted to fix 7 requests on load so I put everything in one useEffect with debounce function.

What I have a problem with is that if some dependency changes I need to set another dependency. Which is a problem when I go back from /clients:id. These are the rules:

1. If company filter changes, agent filter should be empty - setSelectedUser(''), but only if company filter has a value - if a company is selected and then the selected company value goes to '', then agent value stays.
2. If search, pageSize, company or selected agent value changes, page value should be 0 (first page)

Here is the code:

```
const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState<any>(10);
const [selectedCompany, setSelectedCompany] = useState<any>('');
const [totalClients, setTotalClients] = useState(0);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [page, setPage] = useState<any>(0);
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<any>('');
const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState<any>('');
const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState<any>([]);
const [allUsersCopy, setAllUsersCopy] = useState<any>([]);

const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

const searchValueRef = useRef('');
const selectedUserRef = useRef();
const selectedCompanyRef = useRef();
const pageRef = useRef();
const pageSizeRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    if (searchParams.get('search')) setSearchValue(searchParams.get('search'));
    if (searchParams.get('agent')) setSelectedUser(searchParams.get('agent'));
    if (searchParams.get('company')) setSelectedCompany(searchParams.get('company'));
    if (searchParams.get('page')) setPage(JSON.parse(searchParams.get('page') || '0'));
    if (searchParams.get('pageSize')) setPageSize(JSON.parse(searchParams.get('pageSize') || '0'));
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedCompany && allUsersCopy) {
        const filtered = allUsersCopy.filter((e: any) => e.company._id === selectedCompany);

        setAllUsers(filtered);
        if (selectedCompanyRef.current !== selectedCompany && selectedCompany && !!searchParams.get('agent')) {
            setSelectedUser('');
        }
    }
}, [selectedCompany, allUsersCopy]);
useEffect(() => {
    if (totalClients && totalClients < (page + 1) * pageSize - pageSize + 1) {
        setPage(0);
    }
}, [totalClients]);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
}, [selectedCompany, selectedUser, pageSize, page]);

useEffect(() => {
    let params: any = {};
    if (searchValue) params = { ...params, search: searchValue };
    if (selectedUser) params = { ...params, agent: selectedUser };
    if (selectedCompany) params = { ...params, company: selectedCompany };
    if (page) params = { ...params, page: page };
    if (pageSize) params = { ...params, pageSize: pageSize };

    setSearchParams(params);

    if (selectedCompany && selectedCompanyRef.current !== selectedCompany) {
        const filtered = allUsersCopy.filter((e: any) => e.company._id === selectedCompany);
        setAllUsers(filtered);
    }
    if (!selectedCompany && selectedCompanyRef.current !== selectedCompany) {
        setAllUsers(allUsersCopy);
    }
    let curPage = page;
    if (selectedCompanyRef.current !== selectedCompany) {
        console.log('not the same');
    }
    if (
        (selectedCompany !== selectedCompanyRef.current &&
            selectedCompany === searchParams.get('company') &&
            !searchParams.get('page')) ||
        (selectedUserRef.current !== selectedUser &&
            selectedUser === searchParams.get('agent') &&
            !searchParams.get('page')) ||
        pageSizeRef.current !== pageSize
    ) {
        setPage(0);
        curPage = 0;
    }
    pageRef.current = page;
    pageSizeRef.current = pageSize;
    selectedUserRef.current = selectedUser;
    const delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(async () => {
        if (
            searchValue !== searchValueRef.current &&
            searchValue === searchParams.get('search') &&
            !searchParams.get('page')
        ) {
            setPage(0);
            curPage = 0;
        }
        const clients = await getAllClients(
            selectedCompany,
            curPage * pageSize,
            pageSize,
            searchValue,
            selectedUser,
        );
        setTotalClients(clients.totalDocuments);
        setData(clients.data);
        setLoading(false);

        searchValueRef.current = searchValue;
    }, 700);
    selectedCompanyRef.current = selectedCompany;

    return () => clearTimeout(delayDebounceFn);
}, [page, selectedUser, selectedCompany, selectedUser, pageSize, searchValue, showAssignClient]);
```

Now my problem in this code is: When I'm on a second page and I type 'a' in search. I'm still on the second page and if I enter one of the clients and go back, the useEffect that sets everything from query in URL changes the page back to 0. So currently I have these problems -on load sets the page to 0 (even though it has to because of the change of another dependency) and on search change it doesn't go back to page 0.

This is how I currently tried to fix the problem with search and page 0:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (totalClients && totalClients < (page + 1) * pageSize - pageSize + 1) {
        setPage(0);
    }
}, [totalClients]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider restructuring your code. Please use `useReducer` hook to update related states together. You can find more at https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer .

This way, you don't have to use `useEffect` to sync states.

Comment: I will try this. thank you for directing me to the right path.